# PID checker will not work when running through crontab

Tags: bash, postgresql, cron, pid

Okay, so I have a script that contains an infinite loop that checks a postgres database. That works fine. In order to ensure that the process will continue to run I am using cron to continue to execute the file every minuet. To stop multiple instances of this I wrote this PID check script.

```
 SCRIPTNAME=`basename $0`
 PIDFILE="/var/run/${SCRIPTNAME}.pid"

if [ -e ${PIDFILE} ]; then
    PID=`cat ${PIDFILE}`;

    echo "Found PID ${PID}"

    RUNNING=`ps -p ${PID} -o pid=`
    if [ ${RUNNING} -eq ${PID} ]; then
        RUNNINGNAME=`ps -p ${PID} -o command=`
        if [ `echo "${RUNNINGNAME}" | grep -c *${SCRIPTNAME}*` -eq "1" ]; then
            echo "${SCRIPTNAME} is already running."
            exit 1
        else
            echo "Wrong PID file."
        fi
    else
        echo "Outdated PID file."
    fi
else
    echo "No PID file."
fi
echo $$ > ${PIDFILE}
```

When I run the process with `./script.sh` it will not let me run another instance in a different command line. But the issue is that when I initialize this in cron it will create multiple instances seemingly without regard for my pid check. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Are you certain that the environment that cron executes in has a proper `PATH` variable to find cat/echo/ps/grep? Do you have `#!/bin/bash` at the beginning of your script so that you're certain it's being run through the correct interpreter?

Comment: +1, good first Question. How about turning on debugging/trace with `set -vx` and redirecting all output on your crontab cmd line like `59 23 24 03 * /path/to/MyProg.sh > /tmp/myProg.Trace 2>&1` ? Good luck

Comment: Thanks for the help, I fixed it. I ended up getting rid of the if statement `if [ echo "${RUNNINGNAME}" | grep -c *${SCRIPTNAME}* -eq "1" ]; then
            echo "${SCRIPTNAME} is already running."
            exit 1` and just told it to exit 1 if the stored pid matches the running pid. Sorry I wasted your time.

Comment: you can post your revised script as an answer to your question, and then accept it after 48 hrs, to increase your reputation points. Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By simply removing the section of code

`if [ echo "${RUNNINGNAME}" | grep -c *${SCRIPTNAME}* -eq "1" ]; then

echo "${SCRIPTNAME} is already running." 
exit 1
fi`

and replacing it with a simple `exit 1` I was able to get it to work.

For some reason, cron does not like this part of the script. When running it manually, it is good to keep this as it will help in the eventuality that your script is actually the script that is running under the stored pid. This is a small chance and would generally only happen due to user error, but building for the possibility of this is a good Idea.

I am still unsure why this breaks in cron, but it does.